# Custom header layout with AppBarLayout and Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, header, toolbar, android-appbarlayout

How to develop my custom header with Toolbar and AppBarLayout ?I want to add my own custom xml using this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:supportsRtl="false"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--Whatever textview/imageview you want to insert-->

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: okay thank you, so i don't need this ?
 android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Comment: not necessarily, I've got a layout.xml with <linearlayout>, this xml and an include with the layout I want. it's working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to modify header with AppBarLayout and Toolbar

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.A360.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/theme_primary_color"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.A360.PopupOverlay">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPageTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/color_list_item_primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvCounts"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCounts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/count_background"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_list_item_primary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvPageTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvPageTitle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvPageTitle"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabTotalAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_20sp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_20sp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
    android:textColor="@color/black_100_opac"
    />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```